# Why to delegate to consumer the increment of version in t he entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am reading some examples how to implement control of concurrency in DDD.

At first, I thought that it is responsability of the infraestrcuture, or the repository, because the domain only should to be responsible of the core bussiness. But I have seen many examples in which the domain entity has a property for the version.

Then, in the consumer, in the application layer, it is seen in this way:

```
public void MyApplicationMethod()
{
    Order myOrder = _orderRepository.Get(1);
    myOrder.UpdateComments("another comments");
    //If I arrive here, I could update, so I can increase the version.
    myOrder.IncreaseVersion();
    _orderRepository.Commit();
}
```

But I don't know why is the consumer of the domain which has to increase the version. Perhaps the reason is because the domain isn't the responsability to control de concurrence or control the version, because it is not really a rule of the bussiness. But if this would be true, then why to have a property and a method to increase the version?

But if it is allowed or not bad solution that the domain knows about the version and has the method. Why to delegate the increase version to the client? Why not to increase the version in the update method of the entity? Something like that:

```
public class Order
{
    private int _version;
    bool _isVersionIncreased = false;

    private void IncreaseVersion()
    {
        if(_isVersionIncreased == false)
        {
            _version += _version;
            _isVersionIncreased = true;
        }
    }



    public UpdateComments(string paramComments)
    {
        _comments = paramComments;
        IncreaseVersion();
    }
}
```

In this way I can simplify the code in the consumer. Also, if the entity is modified many times, with the variable _isVersionIncreased I can ensure I will increase only once the version, if I update many properties with different methods. The drawback is that I want to update again the same entity after a commit, I would have to rest the variable or load the entity again from the repository. But normally I use to create a new context for each action, so it is not a big problem.

In sumary, I would like to know which is a good way to control concurrency in DDD, and what problems could have my solution, to increase the version in the entity method, instead of do int in the consumer (application layer).

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that DDD has an oppinion on this topic. Maybe it's just the samples that you've seen? EF increments the version by itself if properly configured, so really don't have to increment it anywhere, but technically it's in the infrastructure layer as EF belongs there. My order of preference would be: done automatically by the ORM, done manually in the infra layer, encapsulated in the entity/aggregate and last resort, do it inn the application layer (what you have seen in the samples).

Comment: Really i am in the same opinion, but I have doubt with one case. Supose an order and order item. If I add a new order item. EF will not increment the version, and if I have to check for example the order will not have more than N lines, I would need to control the version.

Comment: Well, I missed this in my comment. If I have an aggregate like an order with order items, all operations go through the root. order.AddItem will "touch" the root somehow. I've done different things overtime, but generally I do MarkUpdated() inside the AddItem which is a method in AggregateRootBase which will maybe set UpdatedAt to UtcNow. This will make EF update the root and increment its version every time something changes in the aggregate, even if it's a child object.

Comment: Then it is similar to the solution that I propse in the original post, that is the domain who increment the version of the root, instead of the application layer. Perhaps it is let the domain handle concurrency than perhaps it more a persistance concern, but really all the examples that I see the entity domain has a property version for this.

Comment: Yeah, it is similar. It's not the same because the way I do it the domain is only in charge of "marking" the aggregate as modified, it can be anything and the infrastructure uses that information to decide if it needs to submit an UPDATE command and also to take care of the concurrency checks. Note that with this approach, you could switch between optimistic and pesimistic concurrency checks in the infra layer without having to change the domain or application layer